# Why does Vagrant status show destroyed VMs?

Tags: vagrant

I have a directory that contains a Vagrantfile file that created three virtual machines, app1, app2, and db for me.  I'm now done with them so I ran the `vagrant destroy [vm]` against each of them.  If I run `vagrant global-status` I can see they're gone.  However, if I run `vagrant status` I still see them:

Current machine states:

```
app1          not created (virtualbox)
app2          not created (virtualbox)
db            not created (virtualbox)
```

Why does the status command still show these boxes?  The Vagrant
[Destroy](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/destroy.html) doc says, "After running this command, your computer should be left at a clean state, as if you never created the guest machine in the first place."  It would appear these machines appear because of there are three subdirectories:

```
.vagrant/machines/app1
.vagrant/machines/app2
.vagrant/machines/db
```

Why doesn't Vagrant destroy them too?  Is it safe for me to just delete .vagrant/machines recursively myself?

Answer (score 0):

The status is accurate. It's going to look at your vagrant file and your currently created boxes and tell you that nothing is currently created or running. If you look at those folders you will notice they are empty after things are destroyed. You can safely delete them if you want.